# Bypass AndroidX Migration error without disabling Lint

Tags: android, gradle, migration, androidx, lint

Now Android force developers to migrate to AndroidX, so i'm getting this lint error.

```
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: Lint found errors in the project; aborting build.

Fix the issues identified by lint, or add the following to your build script to proceed with errors:
...
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
...

build.gradle:31: Error: so we recommend that you migrate to AndroidX libraries when using Android Q and moving forward. The IDE can help with this: Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX... [GradleCompatible]
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

So i want to bypass this check without proceeding with errors in the other hand.

I know that i can disable specific rules with lint but i can't find that rule that allow me to overcome this issue (Migration to AndroidX).

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can suppress this error like this:

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
```

Or you can add this to your build.gradle file:

```
android {
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @shmakova, i was searching for the first answer !!